# Eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent: proof check

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm aware of

- [How to prove that eigenvectors from different eigenvalues are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe)
- [Finite sum of eigenspaces (with distinct eigenvalues) is a direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40966/finite-sum-of-eigenspaces-with-distinct-eigenvalues-is-a-direct-sum)
- [Proof of "Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696327/proof-of-eigenvectors-corresponding-to-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-indep?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Eigenvectors are linearly independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590278/eigenvectors-are-linearly-independent?rq=1)

and likely more.  However, I'd like to check the following proof; I'll gladly delete and/or post a different answer to the non-duplicate one of those if desired.

**Theorem**: with $\vec a,\vec b$ eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $x,y$, we have $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are linearly independent.

**Proof**: we have $A\vec a=\vec ax$ and $A\vec b=\vec by$ where $x-y\neq0$.  Hence

$$\vec a·\vec b=\frac{x-y}{x-y}\;(\vec a·\vec b)=\frac{x(\vec a\cdot\vec b)-y(\vec b\cdot\vec a)}{x-y}=\frac{(A\vec a)\cdot\vec b-(A\vec b)\cdot\vec a}{x-y}=\frac{A(\vec a\cdot\vec b-\vec b\cdot\vec a)}{x-y}=0$$
which implies linear independence.

---

As an aside, I'm curious if a step such as $\vec a\cdot(A\vec b)=(\vec a A)\cdot\vec b$ is valid; I was originally experimenting with such expressions.  I was interpreting matrix-vector multiplication as commutative, so we would derive $\vec a·(A\vec b)=(A\vec a)·\vec b$.  Is *this* a valid identity?

Comment: The last step is totally wrong. Note that $A\vec a\cdot\vec b$ is a scalar and $A(\vec a\cdot\vec b)$ is a scalar multiple of a matrix. Your experimentation is correct if and only if $A$ is synmetric.

Comment: Two comments: 1) your next to last equality does not make sense: $(Aa)\cdot b$ is a scalar, but $A(a\cdot b)$ is, if something, a matrix. 2) There is no need to use the dot product at all. This property is true at the level of vector spaces.

Comment: This argument cannot possibly work, because it's just not true that eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues need to be orthogonal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well.. it is true if the matrix is symmetric and your space is Euclidean, as Ted Shifrin pointed out.